# How to upload an HTML file into python?

Tags: python, html, json

Im trying to write a python (2.7) program that can load a set of html files, search the files for certain variables and then extract the variables in json. Does anyone have an idea where to start, what commands or modules to import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might need [beautifulsoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/), this will help to parse the html.

You can open the html file using builtin python [open funciton](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files)